# Why does a working package get labelled as 'broken'upon removal

Tags: ubuntu, package, apt-get

I'm sort of a linux newbie and have been setting up my system, when I see odd behavior upon removing a package.

Namely, when I try to use Synaptic to remove a package that has been freshly installed, it sometimes complains that the package is broken and I cannot complete my task. A second attempt usually suffices to remove the package, but I don't understand what's going on.

How does a freshly installed package 'break'? Why should there be a problem removing a 'broken' package and why is a 'working' solution to just try the *exact* same thing again, immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running Ubuntu (The best `linux` distribution), Right ? I think the problem you are facing is because of your Operating System, I guess some of your packages are broken You should try these shell commands - This may take some of your precious time.

```
$ sudo su
```

Then Enter your password

```
# apt-get clean
# apt-get autoclean
# apt-get update
# apt-get upgrade
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# reboot
```

If you are facing problems regarding Broken packages then first of all remove that package by first checking dependencies and then forcefully remove that package, and don't ever forget to reboot when you do make enormous changes in your system. To remove that package use these shell commands

```
# apt-cache rdepends package-name
# apt-get --purge remove --force package-name
```

This worked for me, Try this, I believe this will fix all your problems, Good luck.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try this the next time it comes up